# How to merge 2 similar apex controller method into 1 for 2 different <apex:actionFunction>

Tags: actionfunction

I have 2 different apex:actionFunction, one is for save, the other is for saveAndNew:

```
<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="save" action="{!save}" status="sub-status"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="saveandnew" action="{!saveAndNew}" status="sub-status"/>
</apex:form>
```

currently, I am using 2 controller methods to make them work, 'save' and 'saveAndNew'

```
public PageReference save(){
//save codes here
PageReference pageRef= new PageReference('/'+returnId);
pageRef.setRedirect(true)}

public PageReference saveAndNew(){
//the same save codes
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/page2');
pageRef.setRedirect(true);
return pageRef;}
```

The problem is, both methods have the same line of codes for 'save' and the only difference is the returned page reference. How can I make this into one method? can I use apex:param? if so, how may I write it? I'm so stuck on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posts such as [apex:actionFunction with apex:param Param not setting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46017/apexactionfunction-with-apexparam-param-not-setting) show how to pass parameters in `apex:actionFunction` calls. While it is possible and sometimes a good idea to do it, the necessary code isn't particularly elegant or clear. So for your case factoring out the common code in Apex (or just leaving a small amount of duplication) is probably the cleaner approach:

```
public PageReference save() {
    return save('/'+returnId);
}

public PageReference saveAndNew() {
    return save('/apex/page2');
}

private PageReference save(String nextUrl) {
    // save code here
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(nextUrl);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```

Comment: Posted at the same time you did @keith :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new method with below code and pass the page reference parameter into it

```
    public PageReference save(string pageref){
    //common save code
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(pageref);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```

Pass apex param from action function and you can achieve your desired result.